# Why the following code can work on Mac, but it break on my linux

Tags: c

1. it is a simple code for sorting string.
2. the output on my Mac is the following picture.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO8xM.png)

but on the linux : it shows like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s6m3.jpg)

By the way, the version of Gcc in my Mac and linux are Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 and gcc 4.8.5 20150623.

I am looking forward your suggestion. Thank you.

the code is here.

---

As
I add `printf("Hello\n")` in the beginning of the `main` function and the code called the `sort` function. And on the linux, I still use the command `cc filename` and run the `./a.out`.  it just show an output of `Hello`, and the cursor keeps flashing under the Hello message.  the compiler in the linux is likely to make something wrong on the compile call the `sort` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}

typedef int (*fptrOperation)(const char *, const char *);

void sort(char *array[], int size, fptrOperation operation) {
    int swp = 1;

    while (swp) {
        swp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            if (operation(array[i], array[i + 1]) > 0) {
                swp = 1;
                char *tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void displayNames(char *names[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s  ", names[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char *names[] = { "Bob", "Ted", "Carol", "Alice", "alice" };
    sort(names, 5, compare);
    displayNames(names, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program prints text as output. Please copy-paste the text *as text* into the question body. Not as links to local files on your own system.

Comment: I have modified. you can check now. thank you

Comment: Does it give any output on Linux or just freezes? In the image that you uploaded I don't see any 'break'.

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, it runs under valgrind and gdb without problems and shows the correct output (Ubuntu).

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how exactly you compile the programs, both on Mac and Linux?

Comment: This is also a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I compile the programs with the same command (cc filename ), but on the Mac it return the right result. On the liunx, it seem fall in a limitless loop....

Comment: Are you sure the code you run is actually the code you compile? Add `printf("Hello\n");` at the beginning of your `main` function and see what output you get. Also show the verbatim commands you use to compile and run the code on linux. [Edit]  your question and don't post pictures of text but put the verbatim text.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I do as you suggestion and it show the Hello message in the begging and the cursor still keep flash under the Hello message.

Comment: @m0derate well, use your debugger, that shouln'd be too hard to debug. If you don't know how to use your debugger and if you are not willing to learn it then you can still put some `printf`s into the `sort` function and see what happens.

Comment: @m0derate I've tested this code using gcc 7.3.0 on linux kernel 4.15.0 and works fine. I get the same result that you reported on the Mac output

Comment: The source code in your question, was that copy-pasted from the Mac or from the Linux machine? Please double-check that the two are identical; not at face value but with a diff tool.

Comment: I tried the posted code on my Mac, using both llvm 6.0 and gcc 4.6.3.  It worked properly, and identically, under both compilers.

Comment: Code copy/pasted compiles and works correctly on MSVC.

Comment: Again, *please* include the output in your question as text, formatted as code (use the `{}` button), *not* as links to images of text. I see nothing wrong with your program, and it works correctly on my Linux system. Please check that you have the exact same source file on both systems; `md5sum filename.c` should produce the same output. If your source file is called `foo.c`, try `cc foo.c -o foo && ./foo` on both systems. Add this: `printf("compare(\"%s\", \"%s\")\n", s1, s2);` to your `compare` function (it should produce 16 extra lines of output, which should still be identical).